# Passing in variables into a string

Tags: php

Not sure if PHP can do this so I thought I'd ask the experts:

I want to have an array of strings within which I have a placeholder:

```
array (
  1 => "this is string $1",
  2 => "this is string $2");
```

I then want to reference this in many pages and pass the value dependent on the page:

e.g. 
print (array['1'], "value to replace $1")

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Does the placeholder need to be different for each array value?  ie., is there a reason why both strings in your example aren't using "$1" as the placeholder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf)

```
echo sprintf('this string is %s', $array[1]);
```

Comment: That wouldn't work in the case of localization of strings. - the order of tokens could be different.

Comment: If you are doing it right, this works with localized strings too: `sprintf(translate('this string is %s'), translate($array[1]));` and `this string is %s` gets translated into `Der Text lautet %s` (and `$array[1]` to something "I-dont-care" ;)). Everythings fine here. With numbered placeholders, you can even change the order `%2$s is the second parameter and %1$s is the first`

Comment: No, it is not - "This is $1 of $2" -> "Sore wa $2 no $1" EDIT: Right, haven't tought of that.

Comment: @Erbureth: Maybe you wrote your comment, before I submitted my edit, but read it, or even better: Read the manual section about `sprintf()`. `This is %1$s of %2$s` --> `Sore wa %2$s no %1$s`

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.  (@KingCrunch, I'm not specifically trolling you today, I combing all instances of this antipattern on SO and it just so happens that you've been using this antipattern several times)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend regular expressions to replace tokens with text.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Example:

```
$template = "Invoice was issued on <<ISSUED-DATE>> and has to be paid on <<DUE-DATE>> at the latest";

$patterns = array(
  "/".preg_quote("<<ISSUED-DATE>>")."/",
  "/".preg_quote("<<DUE-DATE>>")."/"
);
$replacements = array(
  $issued,
  $due
);
$newtext = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $template);
```

Comment: Regular expressions are just oversized for simple string replacements.

Comment: I agree - a little oversized however, it then let's me place multiple strings in any order.  I like this theory but will go with sprintf() to start.  THis provides a lot more flexibiility for down the track